# Ruby gibberish gem in PHP ? Encryption and decryption of a string

Tags: php, ruby, encryption

How can I implement ruby gibberish gem in PHP, is there any library for it?

I have these settings in encrypted string,

```
cipher = Gibberish::AES.new('something')
cipher.encrypt(string)
#output
#{"v":1,"adata":"","ks":256,"ct":"'+encrypted+'","ts":96,"mode":"gcm","cipher":"aes","iter":100000,"iv":"'+iv+'","salt":"'+key+'"}
```

I have tried CypherJS and cypher-js but it doesn't work.

I want to implement all this in one standalone PHP file.
I also tried open_ssl of php,

```
$decrypted_msg = openssl_decrypt(
  "$encrypted", 'aes-256-cbc', "$salt:$password", null, $iv
);
```

This is not working as well.

They are encrypting and decrypting but I want the same results like ruby in PHP , its not giving me the same result as ruby gibberish gem on decryption.

I have also tried:

```
<?php
function nl() {
    echo "<br/> \n";
}
// Encrypting
function encrypt($string, $key) {
    $enc = "";
    global $iv;
    $enc=mcrypt_cbc (MCRYPT_TripleDES, $key, $string, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, $iv);

  return base64_encode($enc);
}

// Decrypting 
function decrypt($string, $key) {
    $dec = "";
    $string = trim(base64_decode($string));
    global $iv;
    $dec = mcrypt_cbc (MCRYPT_TripleDES, $key, $string, MCRYPT_DECRYPT, $iv);
  return $dec;
}
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_get_block_size (MCRYPT_TripleDES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

$stuff="String to enc/enc/dec/dec =,=,";
$key="XiTo74dOO09N48YeUmuvbL0E";

$encrypted = encrypt($stuff, $key);
$decrypted = decrypt($encrypted, $key);

echo "Encrypted is ".$encrypted . nl(); 
echo "Decrypted is ".$decrypted . nl(); 
?>
```

Again this is giving different results.

I feel I have tried everything I could find on the internet, now I am completely clueless.

Comment: Really do not use 3DES unless you have to interface with legacy code.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions...  i guess I will just install ruby in my php server..

Comment: Without looking into the source code of `Gibberish`, I can tell you that the password is derived through PBKDF2 which produces a 256 bit key and the encryption is actually AES-GCM with that key. The authentication tag is only 96 bit long which could be longer.

Comment: yes but I want to do this in PHP or javascript... you are right about AES-GCM